# Npm start not works for me

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, owasp, npm-start

While install owasp jUice shop when i enter npm start it doesn't work for me i tried lots of methods but it stuck..

```
Error: The module '/home/kali/Downloads/juice-shop_9.3.1/node_mpdules/libxmljs2/build/xmljs.node'

Was compiles against a 
different node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSIONB64.
This version of Node.js 
requires NODE_MODULE_VERSIONB 93.
```

I tried to recompiling and reinstalling

When i again install npm install it says

Unsupported engine i tries lots of ways but nothing works for me

I'm doing it in my kali machine

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile the binaries for your new Node version with `npm rebuild`.